Problem splitting string into individual substrings
I have this batch file.
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET String=Ab,cd,Efgh  
SET Length=0  
FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,8100) DO (  
    IF NOT "!String:~%%A,1!"=="" (SET /A Length = %%A + 1)  
    FOR /F "tokens=%Length% delims=, " %%G in ("%String%") do (echo %%G)  
)  
ENDLOCAL

I want to extract single strings separated by ,, e.g. Ab cd Efgh, but it does not work.

There is a big difference between one output of Ab cd Efg, as you have wrote, and three outputs of Ab, cd, and Efg. The method used to perform your task could also be markedly different depending upon exactly how your string is being defined. It clearly isn't being typed into a set statement! Please clarify your task, and provide that information, using the [Edit] facility.

The main problem lies in the unnecessary complexitiy of the logic. For example, the FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,8100) loop iterates over a fairly large range. Wich really isn't needed for splitting a string into parts. Additionally, using tokens=%Length% doesn't work as expected because Batch cannot dynamically calculate the FOR /F loop.
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET String=Ab,cd,Efgh

REM Loop through each part of the string separated by commas
FOR %%A IN (%String%) DO (
    echo %%A
)

This solution splits the string based on commas and outputs each part.

You should be more clear about what "extract strings" means to you... For example, if you want to just display the strings in several lines, you can do that in a single echo command by replacing the commas by new-line characters this way:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=Ab,cd,Efgh"

echo !string:,=^
%Don't remove this line%
!

Output:
Ab
cd
Efgh

On the other hand, if you want to assign each part to an array element, then do this:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=Ab,cd,Efgh"

set "i=1" & set "part!i!=%string:,=" & set /A i+=1 & set "part!i!=%"

set part

Output:
part1=Ab
part2=cd
part3=Efgh

For a further description of these methods, see this answer
